# Localize variables on AJAX call in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to localize the variables on `update_order_review` ajax call. There is no error but still not able to locate in DOM to access.

I have made it work with setting a cookie and accessing from JS which is not worth.

Scenario:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', array( $this, 'some_process' ) );

function some_process() {
    do_action('some_action');   
}

add_action('some_action', function($obj) {
    wp_localize_script('jquery', 'ajax_custom', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        ));
    });
}
```

I am trying to fetch the currently added product on js end and current cart object JSON.

Comment: Yes. we can localize variable with ajax only with wp_enqueue_script hook.

Comment: An example will be really appreciated.

Comment: I do change my Answer with one of my working example.

Comment: Chances are that by the time your custom action runs, the `wp_head` action has already been executed hence your localized variables object won't be included. Try a different approach: include your `ajaxurl` always, but use it only when your condition(s) is(are) met.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to now use:

```
wp_add_inline_script( string $handle, string $data, string $position = 'after' )
```

This adds extra code to a registered script.

It's been available since WordPress 4.5, examples of how to use it:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/